# Pre-filled subject Form

Tags: webforms

I wanted to attach a form to my node, in wich the subject would be already filled with the nodes title.
I was trying something with webforms and views but didnt get any results. Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your problem? Is subject is a simple webform text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If subject is a simple textfield on webform and token module is enabled then you can set this textfield's default value using token.

[image: webform defalut value with token]

Comment: Thanks, Mutant. But what token do I use? I was able to enable the form into a block, in wich I can use in my node, but if I use %nid or %title, it gets the webform's info. I'm doing that with the Webforms Module.

Comment: Tokens are in the form of [node:title], [node:nid] use this syntax to use token as default value.

Comment: Sorry. Wasn't online this weekend. That worked! thanks!